# How to customize the global navigation menu in LightSwitch - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013, lightswitch-2012

I have created one LightSwitch Web App HTML client using C# in Visual Studio 2013. I have connected to the External DB and loaded around 10 tables and created 3 screen templates (Browse, View and Add/Edit) for each table. while running my Application,

[image: As shown in the snapshot the menu is available as a drop-down list]

1. As shown in the snapshot the menu is available as a drop-down list, from the home screen all the browse screens menus are coming under the globalized drop-down list on the top to navigate to other browse screens .
2. My requirement is, i need to use navigation pane instead of that drop-down list in my home screen to navigate to other browse screens. 
   Is that possible or any other kind of customization in practice ?

Answer (score 2):

I have used 2 methods, one demonstrated in the below printscreen: simply use a blank browse screen to add buttons and basically create a homescreen, although this isn't a navigation pane, and by the looks of it you have to many buttons to put on the bottom navigation bar. I've blanked out the names etc as you can see and have a custom theme.

[image]

Alternatively have you looked into a Push Menu on the left hand side of Lightswitch, I got this to work myself and its very good and in terms of how to get it to work, the instructions are very simple and a downloadable project with this menu implemented in, is also available on the website below.

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3247/Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-HTML-Client-Push-Menu.aspx

hope this helps and please comment if you have any questions